# Why ${1\over n+1}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot +{1\over 2n}>{n\over 2n} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can you please explain me why is : ${1\over n+1}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot +{1\over  2n}>{n\over 2n} ={1\over 2}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Each term is at least $1/(2n)$.

Comment: There should be an assumption that $n\geq2$, because the strict inequality fails for $n=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $$n+1<2n, \, n+2<2n, \ldots , 2n-1<2n$$ you have that $$\dfrac{1}{n+1}>\dfrac{1}{2n},  \dfrac{1}{n+2}>\dfrac{1}{2n}, \ldots, \dfrac{1}{2n-1}>\dfrac{1}{2n}$$ which gives you that $${1\over n+1}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot +{1\over  2n}>{1\over 2n}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot +{1\over  2n}=\dfrac{n}{2n}$$

Comment: Change < to >, exactly the wrong way round

Comment: You are welcome John :).